# cloning a gitlab repository to a new device

Tags: git, ssh

I have a gitlab repository that I have pushed lots of files to.

I want to pull those files to a new google compute engine VM.

I sign in with

```
git config --global user.name "MY NAME"
git config --global user.email "MYEMAIL@gmail.com"
```

And the type:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com/MYPROJECT.git
```

but I get the error:

```
cloning into 'MYPROJECT'...
permissions denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am thinking it has something to do with my new device lacking ssh key, but how do I move it to this device which is currently just command line accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that this...

```
git config --global user.name "MY NAME"
git config --global user.email "MYEMAIL@gmail.com"
```

...has nothing to do with "signing in" or authentication.  These are just the values that Git uses to associate a name and email address with commits that you make.

You are cloning from a remote repository using ssh (the form `git@gitlab.com/MYPROJECT.git` is the short form of an SSH repository url).  The error you are getting...

```
permissions denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

...suggests that, as you have surmised, you do not have the appropriate ssh private key available locally.  There are several ways of solving this problem:

- Use something like `scp` to copy the private key to your new host.
- Use copy-and-paste to transfer the private key to your new host.
- Use the `https` URL for your gitlab repository (something like `https://gitlab.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git`)
- Create a new ssh keypair on your new host, and use copy-and-paste to add the public key to your github account.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the 3rd option and it only took a couple of seconds, much appreciated.